# Is touch typing necessary to be an efficient programmer?

Tags: touch-typing

I am 16 and I have been programming for a couple months. I am really interested in computer science and i am thinking i want to go into the field of programming. I just have one problem; I am a very slow typer. I tap at the keyboard with two or three fingers most of the time. I was wondering if I should learn how to touch type if I want to be a programmer. After all though, when programming, I spend the majority of my time thinking about what I am going to type than I do actually typing so I am wondering how beneficial it would really be. One of the main reasons I was considering learning how to type is so I can use advanced text editors like vim with ease. My final question, If you do think it would be helpful to learn, where should I learn and how long would it most likely take for me to lose my old habits?

Comment: @chepner - You're correct in that this should be closed.  But it's horrifically off-topic for Programmers.  It would get closed as primarily opinion based and likely down voted.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure if there is any site where this would be on topic.

Comment: @chepner This question is related to programming efficiency. How does this violate any stack exchange question protocol?

Comment: Yes - you need to learn how to type. The analogy is being a novelist without knowing how to write...you may have awesome stories, but it will take you too long to get them out that it's pointless. Not to mention, the plethora of written communication required - being a sub-par typist will definitely impede your efficiency.

Comment: @Mark Bracket I thought learning to type would be the most viable solution . I just can't break my old habits. Every time I learn, I begin going back to my old ways.

Comment: @banana you'll get it! Just takes a little practice... also, you'll need typing for more than just programming - very few real world dev jobs involve 100% developing and 0% communication with others, ranging from Slack to emails to pull request discussions.

Comment: @chepner **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)** Recommended reading: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know devs that are great at their job and they still chicken peck their keyboards. Learning to think and analyze is way more critical than learning to type without looking.

Having said that, it is damn useful to learn since working with the keyboard is quicker than pointing and clicking. As far as where to learn, I don't know. Just keep typing, keep programming. Eventually, you'll just develop a feel for it.

Comment: I'd posit those devs would be much better at their jobs if they learned to type decently...if only because the 20% of the time they spend writing code, answering emails, writing docs, etc. wouldn't be so painful to them....

Comment: And I'd agree with you. They would probably be better but in reality they're doing fine in their career without learning. Until they pair with me anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Just do not think about it. After 3 years of programming your will study to type pretty fast.

Comment: The truth is that without learning it you'll only relay on your habits, I see a lot of programmers typing with 6/7 fingers, looking at the keyboard... For learning the best is http://touchtyping.guru where you can focus on each letter